# Changing C# Intellisense to be more like VB

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Specifically, when doing the autocomplete, in VB, you can be typing and realize you are on the wrong path, then backspace and start typing again and the autocomplete suggestions will show up.  This works the same way as TSQL as well.  In C# if this happens, you have to backspace back to the period on your object in order for Intellisense to kick back in after you start backspacing.  There are some cases where backspacing in C# doesn't disable the Intellisense, but I think once you select something, then Intellisense quits until you go back to the period.  Is there a setting or fix for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch between the two autocomplete modes.

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the intellisense completion.

Or, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for method parameter signatures when in the braces of a method.

Comment: I didn't see any noticeable difference using Ctrl Alt Space.  Ctrl Space I think will be extremely useful.  I will try Ctrl Shift Space when the time comes.  It should prove useful as well.  I had been typing a comma in the parens to make the parameter types show up.  Thanks for this list.